# how to set json data when I use redis in node.js

Tags: node.js, redis

I have a question and problem..

```
client.set("foo",[{id : 1}],function(err,reply){
    callback(reply);  // OK return
})
```

output OK return, but when redis registered to json data

data:

saved as `[object object]`...

not saved as `[{id:1}]`

Comment: It seems that you are sending an object to save in redis. However it is a key-value store and saves keys and values as strings - it does not understand javascript/json. Regardless of the library you are using it is always best to `JSON.stringify` the this you want to save. Basically replacing the array with `JSON.stringify([{id:1}])` should do what you are expecting.

Comment: @Vasil Dininski thanks.. Json.stringify(data)  for set

Answer (score -3):

You does not need the callback here.

```
// Putting in Redis
client.set("foo",[{id : 1}]);

// Getting from Redis
client.get("foo", function(err, reply){
   console.log(reply); 
});
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem - you still need to stringify the array before setting it.